# Month format in humanfriendly

Tags: python, discord.py, datetime-conversion, pycord

I'm making a Discord bot and for my tempmute command I'll use the new timeout feature. Since the time of the tempmute is variable, I use the library [humanfrinedly](https://humanfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to convert it.
The usage of the library is:

> s for seconds

> m for minutes

> h for hours

> d for days

> y for years

What is the one for months? I've tried with uppercase `M` but it takes as minutes...

Comment: Since months vary in length, it's not clear how many months a time period is. What is March 1 minus 1 month? February 1? What is then January 31 plus 1 month?

Comment: Didn't think about that @md2perpe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I am by no means an expert on this module; however, a quick look through their API supplied me with this. It does not appear there is a month conversion in this module.

https://humanfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-humanfriendly

Comment: I also couldn't find anything about month related. Thank you for the confirm!